# How to Send a Rest API to Autonomous Database of Oracle?

Tags: oracle, rest

I'm struggling to send a Rest API request to Oracle Database (using Postman).

- first issue: there are three types of Autonomous Databases (ATP, ADW, AJS) that will help me. I already created all 3 types in my oracle cloud server.
- what type of authentication do I need to use? It seems "Basic Auth" with user: ADMIN and password that I defined?
- What API endpoints are available to use? it is a bit confusing, in the attached screenshot I reach different articles that I'm not sure which one to use!

[image]

Comment: it depends on what do you want to do 1) 2) allows to you to create/delete/all administrative task concerning Autonomous database - in your case you said that you already created. I supposed that you did this using the OCI console. You can do all taks in the console using this API. 3) is completely different that allows to do standard CRUD operation on data stored in the database

Comment: You are saying that there is three types of Autonomous Databases. In fact there is 4 workloads type (ATP, ADW, AJD, APEX) and 2 deployment options (shared OR dedicated infrastructure). So 8 options

Comment: thanks for your comments.
So to make it more simple, let's say I created an AJD with OCI console and now I need to check available tables in my database via Postman. what should I do?
(Endpoint? Authentication Method?)

Answer (score 0):

ORDS and SODA for REST (3) supports many different authentication mechanisms. JSON document store REST services (you choose ADJ) are intended to be used in server-to-server interactions. Therefore, two-legged OAuth (the client-credentials flow) is the recommended authentication mechanism to use with the JSON document store REST services. However, other mechanisms such as HTTP basic authentication, are also supported.

**The default** when installing on Autonomous is HTTP basic authentication. Most of  examples uses database schema ADMIN, which is REST-enabled by default.

A good first start point is :

If you are working with ADJ, https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-json-database/ajdug/create-applications-ords-autonomous-database.html

If you are working with other ADB flavors : https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/ords-autonomous-database.html#GUID-E2E921FF-2D80-4E32-9660-28506D10BADB

Those documentations provide links to the documentation referred in your image.

e.g to see the SODA collections availables, the endpoint is https://your-ords-uri/ords/admin/soda/latest/.

To find the URI (Service Console / Development / RESTful Services and SODA) :
[image]
[image]
[image]

As I said, the default is basic Auth. You can also disable security and allow anonymous access for Development and Testing

[image]

For relational tables, there is additional privileges to be managed using ORDS PLSQL package before using Postman. Follow the documentation

Hope that this can help

Comment: thanks for the support
I'm doing the same
but I'm not sure why I get a bad request?
(how did you choose this endpoint:           /admin/soda/latest

Comment: SODA for REST is deployed in ORDS under the following URL pattern, where schema corresponds to a REST-enabled database schema. `/ords/schema/soda/latest/*`, this is an extract from the documentation provided, in my case my schema=ADMIN. So the good endpoint is `/ords/admin/soda/latest` and not  `/admin/soda/latest`

Comment: @NavidElyasi Does it help ?